# Thread entering Synchronized block while used with Scheduler

Tags: java, multithreading, quartz-scheduler, synchronized

I am trying to do job scheduling..while the scheduler in itself runs fine, I wanted to use a synchronized block so that no two jobs can run simultaneously(as there will be  DB Access concurrency issues). But unfortunately, the waiting job is not waking on notify

Below is the code used: for the job listener

```
public class SJobListener  implements JobListener {
    public static final String LISTENER_NAME = "SJobListener";
    ExecutingClass ec = new ExecutingClass ();
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return LISTENER_NAME; //must return a name
    }

    // Run this if job is about to be executed.
    @Override
    public  void jobToBeExecuted(JobExecutionContext context) {

        String jobName = context.getJobDetail().getKey().toString();
        System.out.println("jobToBeExecuted");
        System.out.println("Listener : Job : " + jobName + " is going to start...");
        System.out.println("Thread running in jobToBeExecuted :"+Thread.currentThread().getName()+" "+Thread.currentThread().getId());

        synchronized (ec) {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
            System.out.println("SYNCHRONIZED BLOCK"+jobName);   
            if(!condition){
            try {
                System.out.println("Going to Wait");
                Thread.currentThread().wait(200);
                //check the condition again
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
            //ec .execute(context); as scheduler automatically calls this method, explicitly calling it runs the method twice , one by scheduler and the other executed explicitly
                }

        //}


    //Run this after job has been executed
    @Override
    public  void jobWasExecuted(JobExecutionContext context,
            JobExecutionException jobException) {
        System.out.println("jobWasExecuted");

        String jobName = context.getJobDetail().getKey().toString();
        System.out.println("Listener :Job : " + jobName + " is finished...");
        System.out.println("Thread running in jobWasExecuted :"+Thread.currentThread().getName()+" "+Thread.currentThread().getId());

        /*String testCaseName = context.getJobDetail().getDescription();
          QueryBuilderUtil.updateRecordInSchedular(testCaseName,"completed");*/
        if (!jobException.getMessage().equals("")) {
            System.out.println("Exception thrown by: " + jobName
                + " Exception: " + jobException.getMessage());
            jobException.printStackTrace();
        }
        Thread.currentThread().notifyAll();

    }
```

Below is the code for ExecutingClass

```
public class ExecutingClass implements Job{
    private MyClass mc = new MyClass();

    public synchronized void execute(JobExecutionContext context) {     
        try
        {

            System.out.println("--------execute------ "+context.getJobDetail().getKey());
            System.out.println("--------Current Thread------ "+Thread.currentThread().getName()+" "+Thread.currentThread().getId());

                mc .executeMethod( );
                System.out.println("Done MyClass.executeTestCase");


        }
            catch (BusinessException e) {

        }       
    } 


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

Below is the code for MyClass

```
public class MyClass(){

public synchronized void executeMethod( ){
//does the actual processing i.e read write from DB
}
}
```

Problem is..the threads coming later go to wait, but are notify doesnt make the job run..or maybe notify is not working.. I dont know..something wrong..the waiting thread never does its work..
Thanks

Comment: You `execute` method synchronized on instance and `jobToBeExecuted` on class. It is intended?

Comment: sorry did not get the query

Answer (score 0):

Look at this code:

```
new MyClass().executeMethod( )
```

Now even though you have declared executeMethod as synchronized, it is going to achieve no purpose. That's because the Java lock (for synchronized block) is object specific. So 2 threads who are using the same instance of MyClass will block, but if every thread has a new MyClass instance to deal with, they won't.

So replace new MyClass().executeMethod() with something like

MyClass myClass = new MyClass(); // create only once in code

And every thread should use:

myClass.executeMethod()

This will help in synchronizing the threads.

The same argument goes for this code:

```
ExecutingClass ec = new ExecutingClass ();
```

Even though execute method of ExecutingClass is synchronized, it isn't helping with any synchronization because each thread has it's own instance of ExecutingClass to deal with. If you want synchronization, share the object instance between threads.

Comment: did as you said, synchronized the object instead of the class, still its executing twice

Comment: I see that you are creating a new instance of ec in SJobListener every time, so that won't work. What about synchronizing on "context". It looks like that object is passed between ExecutingClass and JobListener.

Comment: Tried doing that also..but it did not help. No I am not passing any object between  ExecutingClass and JobListener

Comment: ok,thanks, I am sharing one instance of MyClass now..and one instance of Executing class...and keeping in jobToBeExecuted() method : the code as synchronized (ec){ while(!condition) Thread.currentThread.wait()} and in jobWasExecuted code as synchronized(ec){ Thread.currentThread.notifyAll();} But it seems, it the next thread that comes...goes to wait..but is never notified..as in it never wakes up..What should I do now?

Comment: updated the code so that my question is more clear, notify doesnt seem to work..maybe I am doing it the wrong way..

Comment: please help still not able to call waiting threads on using notifyAll()